# How to make Audacious to ignore audio file metadata / tags?

Tags: audacious

I simply want to display audio files as full path names, without any metadata being read. When I search for `audacious ignore metadata`, `audacious don't read tag metadata`, and similar, the only results I see is people having issues with metadata not being read.

I tried `Output` -> `Audio Settings ...` -> `Playlist` and

- Title format: Custom
- Custom string: `${file-name}`

but it gets ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Output` -> `Audio Settings ...` `Appearance`, and at the `Playlist Columns` section add `File Path` and `File Name` columns.